# Getting an error from a Lib and have no source code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I get an error on the AddChild function of a component that I use from a Lib that does not belong to me. I do not have the source code. Although the error is thrown making my Main Thread stop, it is not a fatal error and my App would manage to continue ignoring this error.

Anybody have a tip for me to catch this error. By the way it is coming from papervision_phunky.swc, to be more specific from the function:
org.papervision3d.materials::MovieMaterial/updateBitmap()

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could either:

- wrap the call to the lib in a try/catch block: this would require you to do this everywhere you call the lib code, which is not what you'll want to do
- define a global error handler as described [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/global-exception-handling.html). Note that this only works starting from Flash Player 10.1 and AIR 2.0.